# How do I calculate loan mortgage balance, interest, and payment, when I refinance a house and take out a new mortgage?

Tags: finance

So I am actually confused with how to do loan mortgage problems in my textbook. I was wondering if someone can give me some insights to solving this problem:

**Problem:** Ten years ago the Peter's bought a house, taking out a 30 year mortgage for $130,000 at 4.5%. This year (exactly 10 years later) they refinanced the house, taking out a new 30 year mortgage for the remaining balance at 3.125%.

**i)** What was the monthly payment on the original 4.5% mortgage?

**My thoughts** for i) I am thinking we have to use the present value formula which is:

$$PV=R\times\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}$$

So is PV here $130000?$ Is $i = 0.065?$? Can we take $n = 30?$ I have checked with my classmates and most of them seemed to have used Excel, but I was wondering how we can calculate this without Excel.

**ii)** What was the remaining balance after 10 years (the amount they then refinanced)?

**iii)** How much interest did they pay during those first 10 years?

**iv)** What is the monthly payment on the refinance 3.125% mortgage?

**v)** How much interest will they pay over the 30 year term of the refinance?

**vi)** How much total interest will they pay over the full 40 years the Peter's have a loan for the house?

Comment: Don't you mean $i=.045?$  And aren't the mortgage payments monthly?   I would think you take $i={.045\over12}$ and $n=360.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$130,000$ is the present value of the $30$ year mortgage. The family took this loan under $4.5\%$ interest for $30$ years. On the one hand, the future value of the mortgage is:
$$FV=130,000\cdot (1+\frac{0.045}{12})^{12\cdot 30}=500,200.75.$$
It implies the family must repay this much after $30$ years. However, on the other hand, the family is going to regularly pay $R$ amount every month. Then:
$$i) \ \ FV=R\cdot \frac{(1+\frac {0.045}{12})^{12\cdot 30}-1}{\frac{0.045}{12}}=500,200.75 \Rightarrow R=658.69.$$
In MS Excel enter: "$=-PMT(0.045/12;360;130000;1)$". But they stopped paying after $10$ years. So, we must calculate the future value of the mortgage after $10$ years with $R=658.69$:
$$ii) \ FV=658.69\cdot \frac{(1+\frac{0.045}{12})^{120}-1}{\frac{0.045}{12}}=99,592.66;\\
FV=130,000\cdot (1+\frac{0.045}{12})^{120}=203,709.06\\
203,709.06-99,592.66=104,116.4.$$
This much money left on the balance to be paid in the remaining $20$ years. Note: The discrepancies are due to rounding.

Can you continue with the rest?

Comment: Ok thank you, so I get all this, with regards to finding the interest, would it be the future value at 10 years minus the amount paid monthly without interest,for instance:
$$iii)96,942.16-641.16(120)=20002.92$$

Comment: Also one thing I do not understand is, despite your working being very clear, if I input the data on https://www.calculator.net/payment-calculator.html?ctype=fixterm&cloanamount=130000&cloanterm=30&cmonthlypay=1000&cinterestrate=4.5&printit=0&x=67&y=22, I get the monthly payment of  $658.69$, so I was wondering why the answers show different results despite the math making sense$?$

Comment: See my update. The discrepancies in numbers are due to rounding differences.

Answer (score 1):

Using the PV, it's probably easier.

$L=130,000$, $n=12\times 30=360$ ($30$ years), $i^{(12)}=4.5\%$, $m=12\times 10$ ($10$ years), $j^{(12)}=3.125\%$, $N=12\times 30=360$ ($30$ years).

Put $i=\frac{i^{(12)}}{12}$ and $j=\frac{j^{(12)}}{12}$ and $a_{\overline{p}|k}=\frac{1-(1+k)^{-p}}{k}$.

So we have:

1. The monthly payment $R$
   $$
   L=R\times a_{\overline{n}|i}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad R=\frac{L}{a_{\overline{n}|i}}=\frac{130,000}{197.36}=658.69
   $$
2. The remaining balance after $10$ years $B$ is
   $$
   B=R\times a_{\overline{n-m}|i}=658.69\times 158.07=104,116.27
   $$
3. The interest paid is 
   $$
   I=R\times(m-a_{\overline{m}|i})=658.69\times (120-96.49)=15,486.27
   $$
4. The monthly payment on the refinance $R'$ is
   $$
   B=R'\times a_{\overline{N}|j}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad R'=\frac{B}{a_{\overline{N}|j}}=\frac{104,116.27}{233.44}=446.01
   $$
5. The interest paid over the refinance is
   $$
   I'=R'\times(N-a_{\overline{N}|j})=R'\times N-B=446.01\times 360-104,116.27=56,446.80
   $$
6. The total interest over $40$ years is
   $$
   I_{\text{total}}=I+I'=71,933.07
   $$